# How to setup custom css path for node.js markdownpdf?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm trying both gulp.js and grunt.js to convert from markdown to PDF, both of them use markdownpdf npm package.

This is my *gulpfile.js*

```
gulp.task('markdownpdf', function () {
    gulp.src('_src/*.md')
    .pipe(concat('document.md'))
    .pipe(markdownpdf({
        cssPath: '/_src/css/pdf.css',
        paperFormat: 'A4',
        paperOrientation: 'portrait',
        paperBorder: '2cm'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('_dist'));
});
```

Without `cssPath` option, markdownpdf package picks `node_modules/gulp-markdown-pdf/node_modules/markdown-pdf/pdf.css` (I tired to edit this file to confirm that it was picked)

Please help how to setup custom css path.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's worked for me is to start the path with a `./`. The single dot represents the directory with the gulpfile in it.

e.g

```
gulp.task('docs', function () {
  return gulp.src('./docs/*.md')
    .pipe(markdownpdf({
      'cssPath': './docs/assets/pdf.css'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./web/docs/pdfs'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

so '/_src/css/pdf.css' maps to what?

It should respond to relative path notation, so if it picks `node_modules/gulp-markdown-pdf/node_modules/markdown-pdf/pdf.css` by default, then try setting your cssPath value to `../../../_src/css/pdf.css`, assuming `_src` is in your project's root

Comment: i just tried to place pdf.css *one level up*, and use cssPath: `'../pdf.css`' but it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will need back 5 levels.
My gruntfile.js...

```
markdownpdf: {
    options: {
      cssPath: "../../../../../css/style.css",
```